# How exactly does Intimidating Prowess work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Could someone explain how the feat Intimidating Prowess works (standard action? Free action? Swift action?) and provide an example for a hero with 22 Str and 10 Cha? The feat benefits reads "Add your Strength modifier to Intimidate skill checks in addition to your Charisma modifier."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It works as per the standard [Intimidate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate/) Rules.**

[Intimidating Prowess](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/intimidating-prowess-combat-final/) merely allows you to use your Strength modifier in addition to your Charisma modifier when making Intimidate checks. In your case that would be +6 from Strength and +0 for Charisma. It does not grant any new types of actions or otherwise modify the existing uses of Intimidate.

Please review the [Intimidate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate/) rules for Coercing, Demoralising and Influencing found a the link as it is too significant a text to reproduce here. If you have further queries about how Intimidate works, it might be best to raise them as a new question.